# How to multiply n x 1 and m x 1 vectors in numpy

Tags: numpy

I need to multiply an array of shape (n,) and (m,) as vectors with shape n x 1 and m x 1 to form a matrix of shape n x m.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

I tried reshaping the arrays but I'm still unsure about the math involved.

Comment: `np.outer(a, b)` ?

Comment: `a[:, None] * b` multiplying a (n,1) and (m,) to make (n,m)

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions given in the comments (`np.outer(a, b)` and `a[:, None] * b`) are equivalent and with similar efficiency:

```py
In [25]: m, n = 300, 500
    ...:
    ...: a = np.random.randn(m)
    ...: b = np.random.randn(n)
    ...:
    ...: outer = np.outer(a, b)
    ...: broadcast = a[:, None] * b
    ...:
    ...: assert outer.shape == (m, n)
    ...: assert broadcast.shape == (m, n)
    ...: assert np.all(outer == broadcast)
    ...:
    ...: %timeit outer = np.outer(a, b)
    ...: %timeit broadcast = a[:, None] * b
118 µs ± 619 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
119 µs ± 2.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```